Согласование "может + инфинитив" и личной формы глагола
"Соответственно, под соматическим мозаицизмом понимается генетическое изменение, которое может произойти в любой клетке человеческого организма и не затрагивает яйцеклетки или сперматозоиды".
Редактирую текст и наткнулся вот на такое предложение. Ударило по ушам. Считается ли такое ошибкой? Если да, можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на правило, спасибо.

Да, конструкция в предложении "Соответственно, под соматическим мозаицизмом понимается генетическое изменение, которое может произойти в любой клетке человеческого организма и не затрагивает яйцеклетки или сперматозоиды" действительно звучит несколько неуклюже и может вызвать вопросы у читателя из-за неоднозначности синтаксической связи частей предложения.
Проблема в данном случае связана с правилом согласования частей сложноподчинённого предложения. Синтаксически фраза "которое может произойти в любой клетке человеческого организма" относится к "генетическому изменению", а вторая часть "и не затрагивает яйцеклетки или сперматозоиды" может быть воспринята как относящаяся к "любой клетке", что приводит к логической путанице.
Чтобы устранить двусмысленность, рекомендуется изменить структуру предложения. Например:
Соответственно, под соматическим мозаицизмом понимается генетическое изменение, которое может произойти в любой клетке человеческого организма, за исключением яйцеклеток и сперматозоидов.

В приведенном предложении некорректно соединительное значение союза И для однородных сказуемых. Поэтому его лучше заменить  союзом НО с противительно-ограничительным значением, который ограничивает или сужает сферу распространения действия первой части сказуемого:
Соответственно, под соматическим мозаицизмом понимается генетическое изменение, которое может произойти в любой клетке человеческого организма, но при этом не затрагивает яйцеклетки или сперматозоиды.

Да, ваш вариант очень хороший.
